# i am trying to remove windows file path from a file like "\abc\" but i am not sure which command i need to use in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to remove windows file path from a file like `"\abc\"` but i am not sure which command I need to use in Unix.

I tried `tr -d '\abc\'` but it is not working. Are there any other commands I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
echo 'c:\path1\abc\dir 2\file.txt' | sed 's/\\abc//'
```

Comment: Hum, this would break if `echo 'c:\path1\abcd\file.txt' | sed 's/\\abc//'`.  Can be easily fixed though: `echo 'c:\path1\abcd\file.txt' | sed 's/\\abc\\/\\/'`.

Answer (score 0):

The following usually works. There is a function in bash called basename which automatically removes all but the file name

```
filename=$(basename "$fullfile")
```

example

> basename ('C:/test/test.txt')

yields

```
test.txt
```